# Why i am getting t statistics different

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

```
import scipy.stats as st
st.t.ppf(0.95, df=9)
```

Output: 1.8331129326536335

As per this, I should get 2.262 with dof = 9.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.ppf` is calculating a 1-tail inverse cdf. It looks like you're trying to look up the t-value for p=.95, but the value you are referring to in the table is a 2-tailed value of .95, meaning the one tailed value is 1 - (1-.95)/2 = .975. So

```
In [104]: st.t.ppf(0.975, df=9)
Out[104]: 2.2621571627409915
```